# JBoss AS 7 shutdown - connection manager closed before WAR deployment stopped

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

Env: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final.

I have a WAR application using a data source taken from JBoss AS JNDI. When I shut down the server (Ctrl+C in the console), the application receives a shutdown command and starts to destroy its Spring context. However, I use a scheduler to perform some DB operations. When the application is closing, I want the tasks that are currently in the queue to be finished (but no new tasks are accepted - standard JDK Executor.shutdown() behaviour). This works fine when I undeploy the application without stopping the server. However, when I stop the whole server, the connection manager is closed before the application undeployment, which results in

```
14:31:51,604 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011503: Restored bootstrap log handlers
14:31:51,617 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-127.0.0.1-18080
14:31:51,638 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter] HornetQ resource adapter stopped
14:31:51,653 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MY-APP]] Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
14:31:51,656 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jul 09 14:30:56 CST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
14:31:51,659 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2c591927: defining beans [<snipped>]; root of factory hierarchy
14:31:51,662 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] HornetQ Server version 2.2.13.Final (HQ_2_2_13_FINAL_AS7, 122) [5f713ff6-5f86-11e2-a25d-1f3857764d50] stopped
14:31:51,673 INFO  [MY-APP.Shutdown] Initializing shutdown. Already running tasks will be finished, new tasks will not be executed.
14:31:53,626 ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000451: The connection manager is shutdown: java:/my/DS1
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) [spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:575) [spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:818) [spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:874) [spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:882) [spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.my.app.scanner.db.SyncEntryRepository.deleteById(SyncEntryRepository.java:26) [classes:]
    at com.my.app.rules.orphanentries.OrphanedEntriesProcessor.process(OrphanedEntriesProcessor.java:22) [classes:]
    at com.my.app.routing.Router$RoutingWorker.performRouting(Router.java:49) [classes:]
    at com.my.app.routing.Router$RoutingWorker.route(Router.java:32) [classes:]
    at com.my.app.routing.Router.route(Router.java:18) [classes:]
    at com.my.app.transformation.Transformation.perform(Transformation.java:21) [classes:]
    at com.my.app.MyApp.run(MyApp.java:18) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64) [spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53) [spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000451: The connection manager is shutdown: java:/my/DS1
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:137)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000451: The connection manager is shutdown: java:/my/DS1
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:321)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
    ... 28 more

14:31:53,640 INFO  [MY-APP.Shutdown] Shutdown complete
14:31:53,651 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
14:31:53,656 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
14:31:53,837 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] JBAS015877: Stopped deployment MY-APP.war in 2259ms
14:31:56,158 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032018: Destroying TransactionManagerService
14:31:56,158 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032014: Stopping transaction recovery manager
14:31:56,160 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 4567ms
```

In my standalone.xml I have

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:/my/DS1" pool-name="My1" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.172.1.1:1521:ABCD</connection-url>
            <driver>oracle</driver>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
                <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>xxx</user-name>
                <password>xxx</password>
            </security>
            <timeout>
                <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
            </timeout>
            <statement>
                <prepared-statement-cache-size>500</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
            </statement>
        </datasource>
            <drivers>
            <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle"/>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

then, I lookup the datasources in the code:

```
DataSource ds = new InitialContext().lookup("java:/my/DS1");
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

The datasource has to be looked up programmatically and not hard-coded in spring.xml since there can be multiple data sources and their JNDI names are configured in external properties file that the application scans on startup.

Then, the jdbcTemplate is passed to a TableScanner that is invoked with Spring scheduling:

```
public TableScanner(JdbTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void run() {
    // query a table using jdbcTemplate and process the retrieved records, deleting them at the end of processing
}
```

When stopping of the server occurs during run() method invocation, all the retrieved records should be processed and deleted. When the application tries to delete them, the connection manager is already closed, hence the exception.

Is there any way to make the connection manager (or any other JBoss AS subsystem I might need) to wait until the application is stopped?

Comment: You write that "the connection manager is closed before the application deployment", but are you sure about that? You are not allowed to start your own threads in a JEE application, but that is essentially what the Spring scheduler does, making it impossible for the application server to realize that parts of your application are still running.

Comment: I meant "before the application *un*deployment", sorry, I corrected it.
And I must admit that you are correct - spec forbids spawning my own threads. However, I expect a web application to be a valid use case for Spring Scheduling. Is there a way to make the container aware of the application still using the data sources?

Comment: Same here. I'm using `<jee:jndi-lookup/>` to get datasource as a Spring bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I have now found the cause described in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-944 . The solution proposed there in order to avoid it, is to declare the jndi as a resource in your web application, so that it does not unbind from the jboss server before your application terminates.

To achieve this add the following part to your web.xml which sets a reference to your jboss jndi with name "jdbc/myDS".

```
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/myDS</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
<lookup-name>java:/my/DS1</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```

Then instead of looking up "java:/my/DS1" from your code part that points to the actual jndi, you should now instead look up "java:comp/env/jdbc/myDS" which will reference the resource you put in the web.xml that actually points to the actual jndi (that we previously specified as the 'lookup-name' xml property in the part added in the web.xml):

> DataSource ds = (DataSource)
>   ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDS");

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which functionality is offered by Spring Scheduling, but if you had used an executor from the standard API, the solution would have been to add a `ServletContextListener` to your web application, which is invoked by the container when undeploying or stopping your application. In the `contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)` method, you would then invoke something like `executor.shutdown(); executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`, which will stop the executor and wait for all pending tasks to finish. You may want to consider using a shorter timeout when invoking `awaitTermination`.

IMHO the better solution may be to avoid using Spring within Java EE applications, at least when exactly the same functionality is offered by the Java EE application server as well, as in this case.

Comment: The Spring context is notified by the container that the application is being undeployed (either due to "normal" undeployment or server shutdown). The Spring Scheduling executor is a JDK ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor working on a single thread. It has a destroyMethod that is being called on application undeployment. In this method I perform a graceful shutdown of the executor - just as you wrote - shutdown(); awaitTermination(someTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
So this works fine, the executor is closed, but since the tasks currently in the queue are allowed to be finished, they still try to use the DB

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using EJB Scheduled bean? This way jboss will spawn the worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this JBoss AS issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-944), which reflects my problem. It appears that if the data sources are not bound in a static way, via @Resource, then the server does not know that the data source is still in use. I went with letting Spring manage the data sources on its own, which may not be the Java EE way, but gets the work done and is appropriate in my situation.