# Error occurred while unscheduling jobs

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jboss, quartz-scheduler

When i shutdown JBOSS server `(ctrl+C)` results in the following exception

```
12:39:50,020 ERROR [com.kony.sync.console.job.scheduler.ConsoleJobScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) Error occurred while unscheduling jobs for application ID:PaaSJobs: org.qu
artz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'syncQuartzDS': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:jboss/datasources/C
onsoleDB' java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000451: The connection manager is shutdown: java:jboss/datasources/ConsoleDB [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLExce
ption: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:jboss/datasources/ConsoleDB' java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000451: The connection manager is shutdow
n: java:jboss/datasources/ConsoleDB]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:715) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:69) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3785) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:90) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.removeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1458) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.unscheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:965) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.unscheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:290) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at com.kony.sync.console.job.scheduler.ConsoleJobScheduler.unscheduleJob(ConsoleJobScheduler.java:225) [syncconsole.jar:]
        at com.kony.sync.services.context.SyncContextListener.contextDestroyed(SyncContextListener.java:221) [classes:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3427) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStop(WebDeploymentService.java:171) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$100(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$2.run(WebDeploymentService.java:113) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:jboss/datasources/ConsoleDB' java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000451: The co
nnection manager is shutdown: java:jboss/datasources/ConsoleDB
        at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.getConnection(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:163) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:109) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:712) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        ... 20 more

Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

In the contextDestroyed(..)

```
            jobScheduler.unscheduleJob(PaaSConsoleUtil.PAAS_CLEANUP_JOB_NAME, PaaSConsoleUtil.JOB_GROUP);

        jobScheduler.shutdown(true);
        //scheduler.shutdown();
        executor.shutdown();   

        //clear the connection pool.
        ConnectionPool.clear();
        //Closing HttpClientIdleConnectionTimeoutThread through connector utils.
        ConnectorUtils.shutdown();

        //Shutdown the monitoring async executor task.
        SyncEventListenerUtil.shutdownThreadPool();

        //Destroy all console related threads here and deregister all drivers.
        ConsoleContextUtil consoleUtil = new ConsoleContextUtil(logger, false);
        consoleUtil.consoleContextDestroyed();
```

Comment: What should i do before job unscheduling to avoid exceptions ? I have tried as suugested **[here](http://answer.techwikihow.com/280083/jboss-7-shutdown-connection-manager-closed-before-war-deployment-stopped.html)**

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543202/jboss-as-7-shutdown-connection-manager-closed-before-war-deployment-stopped

Comment: Tried the following way didn't help                                 `ExecutorService eService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
eService.shutdown();
if (!eService.awaitTermination(60000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)){
   System.err.println("Threads didn't finish in 60000 seconds!");
}`

Comment: In case of job scheduler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543202/jboss-as-7-shutdown-connection-manager-closed-before-war-deployment-stopped   is not helpful .Is there any way to resolve the JBOSS issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I have now found the cause described in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-944 . The solution proposed there in order to avoid it, is to declare the jndi as a resource in your web application, so that it does not unbind from the jboss server before your application terminates.

To achieve this add the following part to your web.xml which sets a reference to your jboss jndi with name "jdbc/myDS".

```
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/myDS</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
<lookup-name>java:jboss/datasources/ConsoleDB</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```

Then instead of looking up "java:jboss/datasources/ConsoleDB" from your code part that points to the actual jndi which I assume you do with something like

> DataSource ds = (DataSource)
>   ctx.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/ConsoleDB");

, you should now instead look up "java:comp/env/jdbc/myDS" which will reference the resource you put in the web.xml that actually points to the actual jndi (that we previously specified as the 'lookup-name' xml property in the part added in the web.xml):

> DataSource ds = (DataSource)
>   ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDS");

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the datasource to the persistence.xml (no web.xml needed) only and using the @Resource(lookup="datasourceName") annotation on the datasource.
You can spare a lot of boilerplate code with the @Resource annotation, because you don´t have to worry about opening and closing connections, etc.
simply calling "datasource.getConnection()" is enough to retrieve the existing connection. You let the container do the job :-D